# jQuery animate ignores z-index bug

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am using jquery to slide 3 lines of text up, one line at a time. I am using 2 divs to hide the text. The text slides up in between the 2 divs for a couple of seconds where it is visible.

However, the z-index is not working so the text is always visible.

Googling, stack overflow...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show1').animate({'bottom':'115px'},500).delay(2000).animate({'bottom': '200px'},500);
    $('.show2').delay(3000).animate({'bottom':'115px'},500).delay(2000).animate({'bottom': '200px'},500);
    $('.show3').delay(6000).animate({'bottom':'115px'},500).delay(2000).animate({'bottom': '200px'},500);
});
```

The text should be hidden initially by the first div, then hidden again when it slides up into the other div.

Example here: https://codepen.io/bkdigital/pen/NWKXqrN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that your animated text is a child of .hide2. Also .hide1 and .hide2 have the same z-index, so the later element (.hide2) will technically have a bigger z-index. To fix this, add/change the following CSS:

```
.hide1 {
  z-index: 12;
}
```

and then use pseudo elements to overlay the color over the whole .hide1/.hide2 div (since it's not really possible to have the child behind the parent in this case. So also add the following CSS

```
.hide1:before,
.hide2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/udqm8npa/